# exporting logic as a function in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There is a problem exporting basic logic from a API controller in express.js. Below is the code before (working) and then with the logic exported into an external function (not working).

The `GET '/'` request triggers `async.series` to make requests to other sources and returns this to the client as one single JSON.

This works when applied like so:

***app.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.header({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
  async.series([
    function(callback){
      request('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?includes=Images&keywords=' + req.param('SearchIndex') + '&limit=100&api_key=' + process.env.ETSY_KEY, function(error, response, etsyBody) {
        callback(null, etsyBody)
      });
    },
    function(callback){
      request('http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=squidsea-b201-4872-8e57-6fc17238c44e&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=' + req.param('SearchIndex'), function(error, response, ebayBody) {
      callback(null, ebayBody)
      });
    }],
    function(err, results){
      if (!err) { return res.json(
        {
          'etsy': JSON.parse(results[0]),
          'ebay': JSON.parse(results[1])
        }
        )};
        return err
    })
});
```

An attempt to export a function that puts the result array into a JSON object, `unpack`.
***app.js**

```
var unpack = function() {
  return {
    'etsy': JSON.parse(results[0]),
    'ebay': JSON.parse(results[1])
  };
};

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.header({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});
  async.series([
    function(callback){
      request('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active?includes=Images&keywords=' + req.param('SearchIndex') + '&limit=100&api_key=' + process.env.ETSY_KEY, function(error, response, etsyBody) {
        callback(null, etsyBody)
      });
    },
    function(callback){
      request('http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=squidsea-b201-4872-8e57-6fc17238c44e&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=' + req.param('SearchIndex'), function(error, response, ebayBody) {
      callback(null, ebayBody)
      });
    }],
    function(err, results){
      if (!err) { return res.json( unpack )};
        return err
    })
});
```

I have tried various different combinations and am afraid that it could be something simple, however after 2/3 days of effort am yet to find a valid solution. To console.log the first result returns the desired object, the second returns blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the results to the function ?

```
function unpack(results) {
  return {
    'etsy': JSON.parse(results[0]),
    'ebay': JSON.parse(results[1])
  };
}; 

// ...

function(err, results){
  if (!err) { return res.json( unpack(results) )};
    return err
})
```

Answer (score 1):

in your refactored code you are calling `res.json()` and passing the name of a function as its argument.  `res.json()` calls `JSON.stringify()` on the value you pass it, which means what's being called is `JSON.stringify(unpack)` which evaulates to `undefined`.

You probably want to call something like `res.json(unpack(results));`.